# Template does not exist in django 3.1.3 version

Tags: python, html, django, settings, web-development-server

Am using django 3.1.3 version and am quite to this framework. On running the server am getting template does not exist, i tried all the possible solutions provided by statckoverflow but to no avail.

Comment: can you provide your settings.py file and directory structure

Comment: In settings.py , i have set debug = True, then in Template Dirs = 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')].

Comment: Do I need to create a virtual environment?

Comment: yes you have to create virtual environment

Comment: if you give your demo code than i can find what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Add your app in INSTALLED_APPS list, I was facing the same issue my directory structure is also fine then after adding the app in INSTALLED_APPS (settings.py) list it is resolved.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'your_app_name.apps.YourAppConfig'
]

from django.apps import AppConfig
```

Below must be your app configuration (apps.py)

```
class YourAppName(AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app_name'
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion!